# Creating a regression model with filter on one of the variables

Tags: r

I used iris data and I tried to build a regression model with a filter on one of the variables.

```
data(iris)
```

Here is my model - I wanted to see the regression results when `iris$Sepal.Width>=3.0`:

```
gg1<-lm( iris$Sepal.Length~ iris$Sepal.Width[which(iris$Sepal.Width>=3.0)])
```

however I got this output from R:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = iris$Sepal.Length ~
>   iris$Sepal.Width[which(iris$Sepal.Width >=  : variable lengths differ
>   (found for 'iris$Sepal.Width[which(iris$Sepal.Width >= 3)]')

Any Ideas how can *i* set the regression right?

Comment: You may also use the `data` and `subset` argument in `lm`; `lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, subset = Sepal.Width >= 3.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the part of your formula: `iris$Sepal.Length` isn't filtered by Sepal Width, which is why the error is telling you that your variable lengths differ.

You need to filter both:

```
filtered <- iris[which(iris$Sepal.Width>=3.0),]
gg1 <- lm(filtered$Sepal.Length ~ filtered$Sepal.Width)
```